# Django - How to store scalar value (for adding) or percentage value(for multiply) in one column?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem in django - I would like to store "provision" value. But sometimes its value is scalar, e.g. 2.10$, and sometime its value is percentage, e.g. 10%. When I have value 2.10 in database, I should add this value to base price. When I have value 0.10 in database, I should add 10% of base to have final price. For example:

10.0 + 2.10 = 12.10

10.0 + 10.0 * 0.10 = 11.0 (or 10.0 * 1.10 = 11.0)

To avoid having multiple columns (for storing scalar or percentage) and confusion: what to do, if two value are filled, I decided to store string value: "+2.10" or "*0.10". So it looks like, I need some kind of symbolic arithmetic in django.

I should create:
  - model field
  - form field
  - form widget

Example code:

```
class ProvistionWidget(form.Widget):
    pass

class ProvisionField(form.Field):
    pass

def eval_provision(price, provision):
    # if provision starts with *, then multiply by price
    # if provision starts with +, then add to price
    return final_price

class Stock(models.Model):

     price = FloatField()
     provision = ProvisionField()

     def calc_price(self):
         return eval_provision(self.price, self.provision)
```

Comment: I've edited the part about asking for an offline resource (which would make the question off topic). It's still somewhat off topic because there's no code. Can you add some

Comment: The logic you want should be applied in views.py and not in models. Show us the code of view where you want to save the "provision" value.

Comment: Prakhar Trivedi - I do not have views, for now. But I think I should work with models(to put approprieta data * or +), with controllers (which decide how to calculate final price), and views to display appropriete widgets in admin panel.